# Is there a way to reverse inline control to normal expression?

Tags: dynamic, input

We can use `Shift+Ctrl+Enter` to convert an expression to inline control, as stated in [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GeneralizedInput.html). But how to reverse that effect?

**Edit**

As Alexei Boulbitch suggested, here's what I really encountered:

```
DynamicSetting[(Print[f[Setting[#]]]; Setting[#]) &, SetterBar[a, {a, b, c}]]
```

which will create a setter bar after the keyboard shortcut. If I follow what Alexei said, this is the outcome:

```
Print[f[Setting[Setting[DynamicModule[{BoxForm`var = a}, 
        SetterBar[BoxForm`var, {a, b, c}], 
 DynamicModuleValues :> Automatic], 
      {0}]]]]; Setting[Setting[DynamicModule[{BoxForm`var = a}, 
    SetterBar[BoxForm`var, {a, b, c}], 
 DynamicModuleValues :> Automatic], {0}]]
```

Coolwater's suggestion is certainly usable but under many circumstances undoing is not really an option.

Comment: I think the previous form is only stored in the undo/redo system whose shortcut is `Ctrl + z`

Comment: You may select the control in question (that is, the output of Shift+Ctrl+Enter), go to Menu/Cell/ConvertTo and select the item InputForm.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch That's hardly what I expected. It gives something like `Setting[Setting[DynamicModule[{BoxForm\`var = sth.}, 
       SetterBar[BoxForm\`var, list], 
       DynamicModuleValues :> {}], {0}]]`.

Comment: @Turgon For me it works perfectly. On the other hand, you copy-pasted an incomplete code. It can be checked by copy-pasting it into a notebook. Like this it is impossible to understand, what is wrong. It would be helpful, if you post the code for the control of your wish as well as what comes up after the procedure I or Coolwater described.